# Drop out observations by conditioning on other data in R

Tags: r, subset

I have two data sets as below. I want to remove 1st data observations which are matched ID, V1 and user with 2nd data sets. 
How should I do that?

```
   ID     V1   user   V2   V3   V4   ...
   1      1     A     10
   1      2     B     15
   1      3     C     13
   2      1     A     11
   2      1     B     13
   3      1     C     15
   3      2     B     20
   4      1     D     11
   4      2     A     15
   4      3     B     11
   4      3     C     12


   ID     V1   user
   1      3     C  
   2      1     B  
   3      2     B  
   4      3     C
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `merge` function and the `by` argument? See the help for `merge`.

Comment: how should I exclude values by merging?
merge(data1,data2,by=c("ID", "V1","user"),all.x=F)
like this??

Comment: I don't understand why I should use merge function

Comment: Since you didn't post a minimum working example, I don't know what the exact command would be, but `merge` should keep only the rows that match in both datasets.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
merged_df <- merge(data dataframe_1,data dataframe2, by=c("ID","V1","USER"), all.x=TRUE)
```

This should exclude observations that matched.

Comment: That remains only marched ones. I need to excludes matched ones.